# Writing API to use some functions of Windows Device Driver

Tags: windows, api, driver, touchpad, filter-driver

I would request you to please help me out and guide me to the right track.
I am supposed to right an API using the already available functions in the windows Touchpad driver, like I want to have the x and y coordinate every time the touch is made, I want to have the pressure value, and I want to read speed and acceleration values as well.

How should I go about it, I am really very confused right now. I am unable to find any tutorial or help on this, please guide me through.

I will be very thankful for your time and consideration.

Regards

Comment: Not enough information. Are you writing user-mode code or kernel code?

Comment: Thanks bmargulies for trying to help, I am writing this API that is to be used in a user-mode application which will use these functions to perform other tasks, in the meanwhile Touchpad functionality should not be effected.
Actually I want to retrieve the complete map (2D array of points) of the Touchpad when ever a touch (on/off/drag) event takes place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible path is [DeviceIOControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

the second thing you need is the specific control operations for the touchpad. I can't find any evidence that these are documented openly.

Another possible path is [The HID API](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm), since the touchpad is a human interface device.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am finding the information really helpful, thanks again for such a quick response.